# LED bar graph script not working

Tags: led, arduino-nano, arduino-micro, mathematics

I have LED bar graph on pins 2-11. Eventually I want to use a voltage divider to figure out the amount of voltage left in a power supply. Currently, this script should set the number of LEDs on the bar graph based on `round((v_actual/v_reference)*10)`, I am just using some placeholder numbers in the mean time to test this portion of the script e.g. `v_actual` of 5 and `v_reference` of 10. However, the `convert` variable *keeps printing 0*. I've checked that the other variables were passing and they are. What is the issue here?

```
#include <Wire.h>

int ledBarNum = 10;    // # of leds
int vref = 10;     // max voltage of power supply

void setup(){
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  ledBarSetup(5);
}

void ledBarSetup(int v) {

  // logic vref=8; vactual or v = 4; (4/8)*10 = 2 
  // e.g. number of leds we need to light up to represent the total amt left

  Serial.println(v);
  Serial.println(vref);

  int convert = round((v/vref)*10);

  Serial.println(convert);

  ledBar(convert);



}

void ledBar(int n) {

  int startingPin = 2;

  for (int thisPin = 2; thisPin < ledBarNum; thisPin++) {

    if (thisPin <= n) {

      digitalWrite(thisPin, HIGH);

    } else {

      digitalWrite(thisPin, LOW);

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: In integer math, `5/10` is equal to `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `v` and `vref` are integers, which means that integer division will be performed. if `v` is ever less than `vref` then the result will be 0. Multiply first, then divide.

Comment: ah yes I suppose I should have looked up the diff between int and float in arduino. Was completely unaware of this. Doing the multiply then divide method! (v*10/vref)